# PhluffyFotos does not work on Azure SDK 1.3

Tags: c#, azure

I have tried [PhluffyFotos](http://phluffyfotos.codeplex.com/) example on Azure SDK 1.2 and it works perfect. Today I have installed on another (clen) computer Azure SDK 1.3 and I have also want to try PhluffyFotos on it but it does not work. I have problem with this part:

```
        if (!Roles.GetAllRoles().Contains("Administrator"))
        {
            Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
        }
```

It seems it somehow does not load the custom RoleProvider (TableStorageRoleProvider). Do you have any idea what it could be?

I get the following error: "The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.", because of the following exception "'System.Web.Security.Roles.ApplicationName' threw an exception of type 'System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException'".

Can someone test this example and see what is the problem? http://phluffyfotos.codeplex.com/

Firsty I have the "SetConfigurationSettingPublisher" problem with this example, [but I have successfully resole it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/ab6d56dc-154d-4aba-8bde-2b7f7df121c1).

**EDIT:**

I have look deeper into it and I am sure there are a problem with Role provider. Somehow the Roles class do not read config file. Have anyone any idea why?

Comment: "I have a problem with this part" -- Are you getting an exception?  If so, what?  If not, what's the problem you're seeing?

Comment: Yes "Roles" object is not resolved. It says it could not find ApplicationName.

Comment: Hey, somebody uses Azure!  I've been waiting for a question about it for a while.  Cr*p, don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run PhluffyFotos example on Azure SKD 1.3 you have to the following:

1. Change reference Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient from 1.0 to 1.1
2. Move "GetConfigurationSettingValue" to the Global.asax "Application_Start" event.
3. Move Role related initialization to the Global.asax "Application_BeginRequest" event, but you have to ensure that it executes only once. Example:

   private static object gate = new object();
       private static bool initialized = false;

   ```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest()
   {
       if (initialized)
       {
           return;
       }


   lock (gate)
   {
       if (!initialized)
       {
           // We need to check if this is the first launch of the app and pre-create
           // the admin role and the first user to be admin (still needs to register).
           if (!Roles.GetAllRoles().Contains("Administrator"))
           {
               Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
           }


           if (!Roles.GetUsersInRole("Administrator").Any())
           {
               Roles.AddUserToRole(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DefaultAdminRoleUser"), "Administrator");
           }


           initialized = true;
       }
   }


   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem with my own project. I verified with Fusion logs that the assembly which contains the custom providers dont even load. so it seems the problem is somehow related to the web.config settings being ignored.

Comment: Yes my thouths are the same. Configuration is not loaded. Maybe a SDK bug or some mayor change?

Answer (score 1):

I posted a version of the code with the fixes suggested by Peter to rapidshare here: 
http://rapidshare.com/files/434649379/PhluffyFotos.zip

For those who don't want to fuss around fixing the dependencies etc.

Cheers, 
Daniel